# Is there a way to fire an event whenever a CLR exception is thrown

Tags: c#, .net, exception, visual-studio-2012, logging

I have been asked to add error logging to an application that logs whenever an exception is thrown.

I have a method which will perform the log and I could call this in every Catch clause.

This seems daft as there are literally hundreds of try catch statements in the app.

In visual studio you can set the IDE to break after every exception regardless of try catches, so I am wondering if this sort of functionality is possible to use (albeit not breakpointing the code when thrown)

in summary my question is:

**Is there a way to fire an event (or similar) that would call this method, whenever a custom or CLR exception is thrown.**

as a bonus question related to this, is it possible to do similar with method entry / exit logging?

C#
.Net 4.5
VS 2012

Comment: `"I have been asked to add error logging to an application that logs whenever an exception is thrown."` Clearly the person requesting this has no idea what they're asking.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: My guess is that the application sometimes crashes in production and they don't know why.  Hopefully they really intend to log unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Do you really want to fire an event every time an exception is thrown, or do you want fire an event when there's an unhandled exception?  Emphasis on "unhandled"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want your function to be called just like how Visual Studio would break on a first chance exception (breaks on a throw even inside a try-catch block) then you need to subscribe to the [`FirstChanceExecption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx) event in the `AppDomain` you are running in.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += YourLoggingFunction;
```

You need to do this for every `AppDomain` in your program, but unless you are doing non-common tasks 99% of all programs will likely only ever have a single `AppDomain`

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997368.aspx) for more information about subscribing to other AppDomains if you are using them.

Be aware, you may get more exceptions than you realize, some .NET framework code throws exceptions internally and just have the code in try-catch blocks so it never comes up to the surface<sup>1</sup> or if the library code has the pattern

```
try
{
    SomeFunctionThatThrows()
}
catch (Exception innerException)
{
    throw new SomeMoreDetailedException(message, stateDetails, innerException);
}
```

subscribing to the event will cause you to start seeing both the exception thrown from `SomeFunctionThatThrows()` and from `throw new SomeMoreDetailedException(`<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1: This is most common in network based I/O calls where an exception like a `TimeoutException` would be common but the end user does need to know a timeout error happened as there may be things like internal retry logic that happens before the user is notified.

2: You could also see them in Visual Studio by disabling "[Just My Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx)" and breaking on all thrown exceptions.</sup>